# How to print out string respectively in array of strings in these four situations in C?

Tags: c, string

I try to use these four notation to represent **a array of strings** and test them in order to fully understand them:

```
char juices_A[][12]
char *juices_B[]
char (*juices_C)[][12]
char **juices_D
```

So I write this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int i_A = 0;
    char juices_A[][12] = { "dragonfruit", "waterberry", "sharonfruit", };
    for (; i_A < 3; i_A++)
        printf("%s;", juices_A[i_A]);
    puts("");

    int i_B=0;
    char *juices_B[] = { "dragonfruit", "waterberry", "sharonfruit", };
    for (; i_B < 3; i_B++)
        printf("%s;", juices_B[i_B]);
    puts("");

    int i_C=0;
    char (*juices_C)[][12] = { "dragonfruit", "waterberry", "sharonfruit", };
    for (; i_C < 3; i_C++)
        printf("%s;", (*juices_C)[i_C]);
    puts("");

    int i_D=0;
    char **juices_D = { "dragonfruit", "waterberry", "sharonfruit", };
    for (; i_D < 3; i_D++)
        printf("%s;", juices_D[i_D]);
    puts("");

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run the code, it shows:

```
dragonfruit;waterberry;sharonfruit;
dragonfruit;waterberry;sharonfruit;
dragonfruit;waterberry;haronfruit;
```

Apparently the third and fourth situation has some problem, I want to why. Besides, can I use something like `*juice++` or `*juice--`?

Comment: Hint: check the data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int i_C=0;
char (*juices_C)[12] = (char [][12]){ "dragonfruit", "waterberry", "sharonfruit", };
for (; i_C < 3; i_C++)
    printf("%s;", juices_C[i_C]);
puts("");

int i_D=0;
char **juices_D = (char *[]){ "dragonfruit", "waterberry", "sharonfruit", };
for (; i_D < 3; i_D++)
    printf("%s;", juices_D[i_D]);
puts("");
```

Comment: This is incredible, what does the prefix means, why need the prefix?

Comment: @LeeWilliam your 3rd and 4th sample  is inappropriate as initializer. this called `compound literal`. this case created a temporary array.

Comment: Do you have some good reference/articles if I want to know more about initializer and compound literals.